# Android MediaStore.Audio.Playlist Query Is Empty

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

I'm trying to do something relatively simple: fetch a list of Music playlists that were created in the Android 'Music Player' application (the stock app, com.android.music, not a third party app) and display it in my own application.  I'm querying MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.  My code looks something like this:

```
String[] projection = { MediaStore.Audio.Playlists._ID, MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.NAME };
Cusor cursor = getContentResolver().query(
    MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, 
    projection, 
    null, 
    null, 
    null);
if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    do {
        // do stuff with each playlist
    } while (cursor.moveToNext());
}
cursor.close();
```

**This code works fine in Android 2.3.4.  However, in Android 2.2 and 2.1, with older versions of the Music Player (1.1.1 and 1), this query returns an empty result set.**

Why is this happening? Are playlists not stored in the same location in older versions of the 'Music Player' app?  I've tried to diff various playlist-related files from the source code of the 'Music Player' app ([available here](http://android.git.kernel.org/?p=platform/packages/apps/Music.git;a=summary)) but I didn't find anything helpful.  Even the older versions of the Music Player seem to manipulate MediaStore.Audio.Playlists.

What am I missing here?

Comment: Have you found a solution for this?

Comment: The published api was changed
I opened a bug please star the issue in here: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=29948